# html message dosen't show up on my work email codeigniter

Tags: php, html, email, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create html message to our clients on my website the message worked fine in gmail but in my work email didn't

```
 $message = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head></head> <body> <p style=\"color:#000000; background:#ffffff;\" > Hello World </p> </body> </html> ";
```

I'm working on codeigniter framework .
configuration:

```
function noreply($obj , $subject , $message , $email){

                        $obj->load->helper('email');                        
                        $obj->load->library('email');
                        $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
            $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://srv02.scopehosts.com";
            $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
            $config['smtp_user'] = "noreply@7spectrum.net"; 
            $config['smtp_pass'] = "xxx";
            $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
            $config['mailtype'] = "html";
            $config['newline'] = "\r\n";        
            $obj->email->initialize($config);

            $obj->email->from('noreply@7spectrum.net', '7spectrum');                
            $obj->email->to($email);            
            $obj->email->subject($subject);                                 
            $obj->email->message($message);
            $obj->email->set_mailtype('html');          
            if (! $obj->email->send() )  return 0;
                        return 1;


        }
```

Comment: <p style=\"color:#fff; background:#000;\" >

Comment: How did it "not work"? No formatting, or other issues?